# LDAP departmentnumber query

Tags: vb.net, ldap

I am attempting to query a list of users that are assigned to a specific `departmentnumber` in LDAP, which I know should be a list of about 100.  The below code only pulls back one member (which last name starts with T, so in my mind it seems like it's only returning the last value):

```
Dim userIds As IEnumerable(Of String) = {"7871"}
For Each i As String In userIds
    Dim de As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://test.net:389/DC=test,DC=net")
    Dim LdapFilter As String = "(departmentNumber=" & i & ")"
    Dim searcher As New DirectorySearcher(de, LdapFilter)
    Dim result As SearchResult = searcher.FindOne()
    Dim res As SearchResultCollection = searcher.FindAll()
    Dim item As ListViewItem = ListView1.Items.Add(i)
    item.SubItems.Add(result.Properties("givenName")(0).ToString())
    item.SubItems.Add(result.Properties("cn")(0).ToString())
    item.SubItems.Add(result.Properties("userPrincipalName")(0).ToString())
Next
```

Comment: You seem to run two queries - `searcher.FindOne()` and `searcher.FindAll()`, but never loop through the results from the `FindAll()` call.  Can you clarify what results you are seeing from thw two calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works:

```
 Dim userIds As IEnumerable(Of String) = {"7871"}
        For Each i As String In userIds
            Dim de As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://test.net:389/DC=test,DC=net")
            Dim LdapFilter As String = "(departmentNumber=" & i & ")"
            Dim searcher As New DirectorySearcher(de, LdapFilter)
            Dim result As SearchResult
            Dim res As SearchResultCollection = searcher.FindAll()
            For Each result In res
                Dim item As ListViewItem = ListView1.Items.Add(i)
                item.SubItems.Add(result.Properties("givenName")(0).ToString())
                item.SubItems.Add(result.Properties("cn")(0).ToString())
                item.SubItems.Add(result.Properties("userPrincipalName")(0).ToString())
            Next
        Next
```

Comment: Making progress :)  By the way, in this context, the `userIds' variable would be more appropriately named `departmentNumbers`.